# Daily cron to poll mysql and update status based on timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have a db full of email users that lists the date and time they signed up in a column called signup_date using the DATETIME type (it uses `now()` ) and I also have an expire_date column which lists the same format but exactly a year later using `ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)`

I have added a status column with values being either 0 or 1. I guess this can be an ENUM type. Upon registration, status is set to 1 for active.

What I want is that if the timestamp of the expire_date is older than the current time, the cron should execute an update on that row of the user setting the status to 0. In postfix, I altered the query and appended the status=1 so that it will select the user with only status of 1. If the status isn't 1, then the user will not be found and won't be able to log in. This cron can run daily. I'm not too anal about having it run every second. Users can renew their emails within the next day. So this is my simple way of expiring emails, if they are not active or so after a year. What I need help with is constructing the cron. Should this be done with just php or does some bash need to be used? Im unclear of how to structure the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why maintain an additional flag column? You can calculate the status on the fly

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
WHERE expire_date > NOW()
```

*This will return only unexpired rows*

If you need status to be produced as a column you can do

```sql
SELECT *, (expire_date > NOW()) status
  FROM table_name
```

Comment: Well here is the problem. The user will still be able login because in postfix, the query is as follows:
`SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'`
 So unless there is a status column, users will still be able to log in. But I can append `AND status='1'` to the postfix query. This way if that user is expired (which I need it to set to 0 when it does), then that user will effectively not be able to log in

Comment: Then you should be able to add `AND expire_date > NOW()` instead of `AND status='1'`

Comment: What a brilliant and simple answer. I never even thought of that. Thanks to people like you, this is how I learn and get better. Thanks alot!

Comment: Well I did try this query in mysql> and it did return an empty set which I wanted, but when I added `AND expire_date > NOW()` to my postfix query, and restarted postfix, it did not seem to have the result I expected. The given user is still able to log in. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I'm not an expert in postfix, but if the query gives you correct results in mysql client then the query itself is correct. Therefore the problem most likely lies in a way you configure it in postfix.

Comment: If anyone is interested, the user with the expired account can send emails but not receive. So this is most likely a postfix bug or there might be something somewhere in the postfix configuration I didn't look over but I doubt it. If the user can send emails but not receive, it is a bit strange and not consistent. Of course at the end of the day, I'd like to get things working 100% but I don't think it is much use to send emails without receiving unless you intend to spam and there are checks for that.